# SwiftUI Half-swipe back from navigation causes error

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I noticed issue in SwiftUI when using NavigationStack

Once I swipe-back on a half and revert it -> it stops working

[image]

Also I attached sample code if you want to try it

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ListView()
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: ViewA(viewModel: .init()), label: {
                Text("A")
            })
                
            NavigationLink(destination: ViewB(), label: {
                Text("B")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ViewA: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: Observed
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List {
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.action()
                }, label: {
                    Text("label")
                })
            }
            
            NavigationLink(isActive: $viewModel.shouldShowViewB, destination: {
                ViewB()
            }, label: {EmptyView()})
        }
        .navigationTitle("view a")
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                print("actionb")
            }, label: {
                Text("labelb")
            })
        }
        .navigationTitle("view b")
    }
}

class Observed: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shouldShowViewB = false
    
    func action() {
        print("action from model")
        shouldShowViewB = true
    }
}
```

Expected: whatever I do it should work as expected - when I tap it should open new view
Anyone else found this issue? How to fix it?

Comment: it doesn't have to do with swipe, also if you use the back button it stops working. only works the first time

Comment: @ChrisR do you know why? do you know any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1 is you create the ObservedObject inside the NavigationLink with `.init` and then have a @StateObject declaration in the Subview `ViewA()`. That doesn't feel right. Create the Object with @StateObject in the parent view and pass it down.

Issue 2 is the new SwiftUI Navigation model, with `NavigationLink)destination: label:)` being deprecated. I adapted your code to the new navigation logic:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ListView()
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = Observed() // create ObservedObject here
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink("A") {
                ViewA(viewModel: viewModel) // pass down
            }
            NavigationLink("B") {
                ViewB()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewA: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: Observed // passed down Object
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List {
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.action()
                    print(viewModel.shouldShowViewB)
                }, label: {
                    Text("label")
                })
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $viewModel.shouldShowViewB, destination: { ViewB() })
        }
        .navigationTitle("view a")
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                print("actionb")
            }, label: {
                Text("labelb")
            })
        }
        .navigationTitle("view b")
    }
}

class Observed: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shouldShowViewB = false
    
    func action() {
        print("action from model")
        shouldShowViewB = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I copy-pasted your code and still the same issue, did you try it?

Comment: yes of course, runs fine with me Xcode 14.1. simulator 16.1 ... strange. can you describe me what happens exactly?

Comment: the same issue that is on the preview, also tried it on Xcode 14.0 iOS 16.0 simulator iPhone 14


if you half-swipe back on view A, the button "label" (that push view B) stops working (might be iOS 16.0 bug if you say that this is working for you)

Comment: updated xcode to 14.2, it is working, thank you!